# How to insert data from one database table to another database table in the two different server using job scheduler?

Tags: sql-server, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduling, sql-agent-job

I have two database in two different server .I want to insert data from one database table to another database table using sql job scheduler.I need to compare two tables rows and based on comparison result i need to put data into another table.

Comment: Schedule an SQL Agent Job with a query that pulls (not push!) the data throughout a linked server.

Comment: Please describe step by step .I don't have any idea to doing these kinds of job.

Comment: this is very simple, you can find tons of info online. I'm not gonna tell you step by step if you didn't take time to try things out before asking.